# How to speed up loading times in my application

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

Currently I'm working on an application that queries a database that has several tables in it, some tables have KeyFields that relate to each other.

If this is the case, when I parse (or load form cache, which I am working on) a dataset that is related to another dataset I would like to create a NSDictionary of related values who keyvalue is equal say equal to selected values keyvalue.

First question is this possible.. Second question what do I need to be thinking about before I look to attempt such a thing. at what point do I execute (what ever instructions) to create this NSDictionary.

To give you a better Idea of what I am working towards check out this flowchart that I have made of my apps proposed logic.
[image]

Im not sure how to make it bigger.. but if you save it to your desktp you will see.. follow MFG to see what I am trying to do.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell me what tool you used to make that flow chart please?

Comment: Hey  James sorry for the late reply, was the weekend and I eneded up sleeping for much of it as I wasn't feeling to flash.. I use this pretty cool website that dose this type of flow chart and heaps of other things. its called (https://www.lucidchart.com/) Its, free but only for X number of objects you include in each of your diagrams.. but there is also a fairly cheap basic version which I use with unlimmited objects I think.. (just off the top of my head) hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to create a dictionary structure like you are thinking, but it can get very complicated, very quickly.  Another method might be to use a custom NSObject subclass to manage the data and relationships which you can then build some behavior into if you need.

To make sure your app loads quickly, do not load this data until after your root view controller is loaded and definitely not in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as this method needs to return ASAP so the system watchdog doesn't kill your app with `8badf00d` for taking to long to load.

I'd recommend loading this data in a background thread that is started your first view controller's `-viewDidLoad:` method.  Make sure it's a background thread and not on the main thread otherwise your UI may be blocked and unresponsive during the loading. If you use a background thread, the UI on the main thread will be free during loading so you can also show the user a progress bar or activity indicator to make it clear that your app is busy, but not frozen and unresponsive during this loading process.

Comment: Okay cool. Thank you very much for your reply. I understand all the things you are saying I am going to do some more reading before I commit to anything just for peace of mind that Im doing the right thing. I think the major stepping stone for me is learning how to use the different threads (I understand them just havent used them in ios development) as so far I have just been programing on a whim :) currently I am using ASIHTTPRequest, along with NSXMLParser, and I put all of my UIActivityIndicator stuff inside the parserDidEndDocument which seems to work ok.